# SSL is required in photos_search flickr api, how to solve it?

Tags: php, flickr, phpflickr

I am using phpFlickr api to serach photos in flickr. I am using following code, but it is not working.

```
require_once($lib_dir."phpFlickr.php");
$flickr = new phpFlickr($cfg['flickr_api_key'],$cfg['flickr_secret']);
$photos = $flickr->photos_search(array('text'=>'BOOKS','content_type'=>1,/*'user_id'=>'me',*/'per_page'=>16,'page'=>1));    
print_r($photos);
```

when i use `echo $flickr->getErrorMsg()` i got error msg `SSL is required`.
So how to solve it?

`later edit:`
once i change api to newer one..it is display `boolean false` error message. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: var_dump, error_log? or nothing there?

Comment: no error..it's return nothing.(testing on local)

Comment: if i use var_dump then this message display:  `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
</pre>`

Comment: try `$photos = $flickr->photos_search(array('user_id' => 'SOME_USER_ID', 'page'=>1, 'per_page' => 1));` just to see if it works

Comment: using `echo $flickr->getErrorMsg()` i got error msg `SSL is required`

Comment: not sure, but your answer might be [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/flickr-api-error-ssl-is-required)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is solved. The api is changed which was I used. so i change few lines in api and it is worked.

i changed the http to https and problem is solved.

you can find more about [here.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/flickr-api-error-ssl-is-required)